# Parallel Processing in R, when to use parLapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

My enviroment is window(Not able to change this).
Hope to use Parallel Processing in R(Rstudio) to shorten the time of runing caculation (Colleberative filltering)

My previous develper chose using parLapply (Socket methord) then i got into this topic.

I read a post here 
http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jerrick/courses/stat701/notes/parallel.html#using-sockets-with-parlapply

states in the end of the post.

> > the additional overhead that can occur with the socket approach - it can definitely be faster, but in this case the overhead which is added slows it down.

which means, parallel computing may not able to speed up in some cases. (for socket, for each node need to load the pacakges seperately)

then is there any matrix can help people decide whether or not use parLapply at the first place?
and besiding of 'Parallel' pakage in R, is there any other package can improve the caculation efficiency shorten the time?

one more stupid question is, for parallel processing in R, it will only help with shorten time but will not able to help with the 'running out memory for large data set problem in R' right? e.g. using ARule package caculated rules

Comment: IMO the best approach is to structure your code using the apply family. Switching to parallel can be almost trivial then. Note that some problems can't be sped up using parallel due to communication constraints. I would have to see the data that demonstrate such a stark difference between different paradigms of implementing parallel computing that it would be worth it while to switch from one to another. Another way of optimizing code is using e.g. C++ (Rcpp package).

Comment: I usually use `doParallel` or `doSNOW` along with `plyr` functions like `llply` using the option `.paralel=T`.  To reduce overhead, you need to experiment and find the right level at which to parallelize your code. Eg: If you're working with multiple files, do you process each file in a seperate thread, or do you process them sequentially and parallelize the process itself.

Comment: Are you computing on a Windows laptop? How many cores? If 2, then 2x speedup is the most you can get from it. Before going parallel, consider profiling your code with `Rprof()` and refactoring to improve speed.